# How do I make :hover inside div style?

Tags: html, css, hover

So my code looks like this:

```
<div id="blackbox">style="background: black; 
width: 90px; 
height: 80px; 
color: white; 
text-align: center; 
font-family: Times; 
font-size: 20px;
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
bottom: 150px
```

Now it somehow doesn't work at the inline CSS, this is the only thing I can get it done.
If you got a solution for that, I'd be greatful.
But so, I want to make the :hover property but how because this won't work:

```
<div style="background: black; 
width: 90px; 
height: 80px; 
color: white; 
text-align: center; 
font-family: Times; 
font-size: 20px;
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
bottom: 150px}

blackbox:hover {background: white;}
```

or

```
:hover {background: white;}
```

or

```
hover {background: white;}
```

Comment: `.blackbox:hover {...}` in a external style sheet

Comment: Use external style sheets. You cannot place pseudo-classes inline.

Comment: You cannot use hover in an inline style, you need to use it in a stylesheet.  Further, if you've got inline styles in your document, if you want to "override" them with css in an external file, you'll have to use the !important declaration.

Comment: <div onmouseover="this.style.color='black'">I wouldn't suggest this</div>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't have pseudo selectors within inline styles.

You'll need to use CSS in an external stylesheet (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />`) or use a `<style>` element.

Comment: Well now here's the problem, my blackbox div won't read the CSS from elsewhere than inline. Not between <style> tags nor seperate CSS file.

Comment: @CladeeLintunen, if you're setting a style inline, it will have a higher specificity than the styles set from CSS, and will therefore ignore the CSS rules.

Comment: How can I fix it? I can't have pseudo code if I can't get it read from seperate file or style element.

Comment: @CladeeLintunen, keep your CSS in `.css` files.

Comment: Not helping. Here's my code:    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="clade.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style3.css" />
<title>SuomiWiki</title>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>
</head>

<body> 
<div class="blackbox"/>
</body>
</html>

Comment: CSS:   blackbox {
background: black; 
width: 90px; 
height: 80px; 
color: white; 
text-align: center; 
font-family: Times; 
font-size: 20px;
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
bottom: 150px;
opacity: 0.5
transition: opacity 5s, background 5s; }

blackbox:hover {
opacity: 1;
background: darkgray;
}

Comment: @CladeeLintunen, comments are not the place for code examples. If you need to write up code examples, create a reduced test case in a service such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @CladeeLintunen, also, you forgot to prefix your classes with `.`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Well I got it fixed with # prefix. Is there a difference?

Comment: @CladeeLintunen, the code you posted in this comment thread uses `<div class="blackbox">`, while the code in your question shows `<div id="blackbox">`. [there is a significant difference between classes and IDs](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/).

Answer (score 0):

**Inline pseudo code**! Not possible.  Try it in embedded or external stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

in the css write

```
#blackbox:hover {
    //write something
}
```

Comment: Potentially won't override inline styles....

Comment: true, but why does it make any concern? pseudo class couldn't be written in inline styles.

Comment: Because your answer is incomplete without identifying that, and how to solve it.

Comment: 99% of times you realy shouldn't use !important

Comment: totally agree, however my point is that this "answer", if taken alone as a potential answer, *will not work* without the !important declaration.

Comment: I have to disagree, you cannot override this rule in inline style, the only case this class can be over ruled is by higher specificity class..

Comment: No, this actually fixed it! The hashtag was all it needed!

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo selectors cannot be used inline. :)
You have to specify it separately it in css.

Comment: Try upvoting the answers already posted, rather than posting a duplicate answer...

Comment: Late to the party.  Time is everything!